# How to merge new git commit history list on top of existing branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, pull-request

In Git, I have two branch:

- `master`
- `v2`

`v2` is a lerna mono repo,

I started the branch by removing the `.git` directory, (this cause the whole history being lost), then I did `git init; git remote add origin $url` in order to recreate a git history which I will push on `v2` branch.

Now that the PR is almost ready to be merged, how can I merge in order to have `v2` branch history placed on top of `master` branch history?

What's the cleanest way to keep a good history?

Comment: The `.git` directory contains the actual repository. If you remove it, you have removed the repository, and are no longer using Git at all.

Comment: Do I have to say that I did `git init; git remote add origin $url` ? However, how do you think I pushed `v2` if I am not in a git repo? It sounded to obvious that I didn't even explained it. (I updated the question since it was not obvious for 3 of you)

Comment: Given that people are always doing that sort of thing without creating a new repository, yes, you really do have to say that you created a new repository. It's still not clear to me what you'd *like* as your actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone again your repository in another folder, while keeping the work you have done in your first folder (the one where you remove the `.git` subfolder)

In that new local clone, switch to a new PR branch

```
 git switch -c myNewPRBranch
```

Then import your work

```
 git --work-tree=../old_repo add .
 git commit -m "Import PR code"
 git push -u origin myNewPRBranch
```

Finally, make a PR from your new PR branch to `main`.

This assumes you can push directly to the cloned repository. If not, you would need to [fork it first](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).

Comment: Thanks mr @VonC, I won't be able to test it out, but I accept it already cause you look to be used to that kind of manipulation. Thanks !